# Show error message for every argument that is not defined in Ruby program

Tags: ruby, io

I'm creating a program in Ruby for replacing content of multiple files in one directory, and there are four arguments:

- **dir** for defining directory
- **ext** for defining extension
- **find** for defining string to find
- **replace** for defining string that replace string defined as *find*

Right now, this is start of the program:

```
dir, ext, find, replace = ARGV
dir, ext, find, replace = ARGV.shift

raise "Missing argument for directory" unless dir
raise "..." unless ext
#etc
```

However, when I run this program without defining arguments, it shows only first argument that is not defined (directory) with *RuntimeError* and imediatelly closes program. Is there any different approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you such variant:

```
missing_parameters = ["dir","ext","find","replace"].select{|name| eval(name).nil?}
raise "Missing parameters for #{missing_parameters.join(',')}" unless missing_parameters.empty?
```

But frankly speaking, i don't like the usage of eval :)